# What's wrong with my Twitter Bootstrap tab / pills?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I can't get pills to work. Here is [my live app](http://btctox.org/api).

I believe I used the correct layout, and called `.tab()` on my tab, but it doesn't work. What am I missing?

The selected tab is not switching on click, and the tab content is not showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot to add data-toggle="tab" on the different a tags

```
<a href="#tobtc" data-toggle="tab">http://btctox.org/api/tobtc</a>
```

replace

```
<div class="tab-content2">
```

with

```
<div class="tab-content">
```

And it's all OK